# Why is my below code for IIFE only working once with the clickEvent

Tags: javascript, iife

Below is a link to a small project I thought of and created today. I can not get the button to work more than once using an IIFE.. I have figured it out without an IIFE, but my understanding is it is best to make code private... Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

https://codepen.io/kclute627/pen/dgPyxq

```
let randomColor = (function(){

// generate a random number 
let randNum= () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
// invoke random number 6 times to create hexcolor
let randColor = parseInt([randNum(), randNum(), randNum(), randNum(), 
randNum(), randNum()].join(''))

const hexColor = (`#${randColor}`)

return hexColor;

})();

const makeColor = (function() {
let color1 = randomColor;
console.log(color1);
let setupEventListener = function(){ 

    document.querySelector('.final-button').addEventListener('click', 
function(){
        document.querySelector('.main-box').style.backgroundColor = color1;
    });
};

setupEventListener();

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

`randomColor` is only ever assigned once when the file is first loaded.  `let color1 = randomColor;` just grabs the value of `randomColor`, it's not running your IIFE again to get a new color.

`randomColor` should be a function (not a reference to the return value of an IIFE) if you want it to run again and generate a new color.  You can scope this whole thing with an IIFE wrapping it all if you want and put `randomColor` in some kind of scope if you don't want it on the global scope.

It's worth noting that your click handler is running every time you click, but the color is not changing because `randomColor` is not changing.

Comment: I see what you are saying any suggestion as to run the IIFE again when the button is clicked?

Comment: Well, you would just turn it into a function instead of have it run an IIFE.  If you want the function scoped, you can create a class and add this as a method, or put it in a variable on the global scope (like how jQuery or other libraries exposes themselves).

Answer (score 0):

On the click event only the function given to `addEventListener` as the second argument will be invoked. The variable `color1` is assigned outside of this function so the value will stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just an extended comment on the *randomColor* function.

I'm not a fan of using a function expression where a function declaration is indicated. The assignment still creates a global variable, doesn't save any characters and introduces issues not present with declarations.

Within the the function, there is another function expression that is called 6 times, then an array created and joined, and finally the use of *parseInt* which will introduce sporadic errors (it will remove leading zeros so the value no longer has 6 digits) and is entirely unnecessary considering you want a string result.

Lastly, the resulting value is really decimal, as it will only contain digits from 0 to 9.

It may be unfashionable to use loops, but they are really fundamental and should be at least considered where they are indicated. E.g.:

```js
// Generate random 6 digit hex value where digits are 0 - 9
function randomColor() {
  var color = '#';
  for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
    color = color + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  }
  return color;
}

console.log('Decimal color: ' + randomColor());
```

If you want to generate a hex value (digits 0 to f), then consider:

```js
// Generate random 6 digit hex value
// This uses parseInt to get hex value, but makes it a string
// immediately so leading zeros are kept if they occur
function randomHexColor() {
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color = color + (Math.random() * 16 | 0).toString(16);
  }
  return color.toUpperCase();
}

console.log('Hexidecimal color: ' + randomHexColor());
```

Or if you must use newer features, and create a more general function, maybe:

```js
// Generate hex value of length len
function getRandomHex(len) {
  return new Array(len).fill(0).map(x=>(Math.random()*16|0).toString(16)).join('');
}

console.log('#' + getRandomHex(6).toUpperCase())
```

Which is shorter, but is very much less efficient. It might be a viable option if *Array.prototype.fill* accepted an expression rather than a primitive value, something like:

```
var randomArray = new Array(6).fill((Math.random()*16|0).toString(16));
```

that was evaluated for each value, but it's only evaluated once and the value repeated for each element.